# Show values in the html table as json array on button click is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

User can enter values in some or all the rows present in the html table and click on the submit button. If a value is present in the row (if at least one column field value is entered) and the submit button is clicked, I want to get all the details as a json array.

Working sample demo :  http://jsfiddle.net/Crw2C/173/

In the working demo above, when the user clicks on the convert button, the data from the html table is shown as a json array. I tried a similar implementation in my demo as shown in the code below but it is not working as expected.

My **sample demo code which is not working** as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/FODEJ1BnhPLGHoH9kjO5?p=preview

Sample html code:

```
<table id="productTable" border="1">

    <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Product1</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product2</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
         <td>
                           <select class="product1" > 
                           <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
              <input type="text" name="description" value="">
                </td>
             .......
```

Sample js code:

```
  $('#productTable th').each(function(index, item) {
        headers[index] = $(item).html();
    });
    $('#productTable tr').has('td').each(function() {
        var arrayItem = {};
        $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
            arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
        });
        array.push(arrayItem);
    });
```

Note: With my code above, the entire html element is retrieved and stored as json array but I only want the value. Any sample code would be appreciated as I tried to search and tried in different ways but was unable to succeed. The sample code I tried I also shared in the demo link above, which is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the whole `<td>...</td>` instead of this select html `input` or `select` elements.

```
$('#productTable tr').has('td').each(function() {
    var arrayItem = {};
    $('td input, td select', $(this)).each(function(index) {
        arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(this).val();
    });
    array.push(arrayItem);
});
```

Check below snippet.

```js
    function populateSelect() {
     var ids = [{"pid":"laptop","des":"laptop"},{"pid":"Mobile","des":"Mobile"},{"pid":"IPAD mini.","des":"IPAD mini."}]
      var productDropdown1 = $(".product1"); 
      var productDropdown2 = $(".product2");
      $.each(ids, function(index,value) {
      $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown1);
        $("<option />").text(value.des).val(value.pid).appendTo(productDropdown2);
      });
        
       $("select").change(function() {    
         var row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
         var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
         var descValue = $('input[name="description"]',row).val();
         if( product1_drop &&  product2_drop)
           validate(product1_drop,product2_drop, descValue);
       }); 
                  
        $('input[name="description"]').on('input', function(e){
          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
          var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
         console.log("-inut -product1_drop----- " + product1_drop);
        if( product1_drop &&  product2_drop)
         validate(product1_drop,product2_drop, $(this).val());
        }); 
 }
 
 function validate(prod1, prod2, desc){
   if(desc && prod1 === prod2 ){       
    alert('Product1 and Product2 cannot have same value');
  }
 }
 
 function submitData(){
   alert("submit");
   var array = [];
    var headers = [];
    $('#productTable th').each(function(index, item) {
        headers[index] = $(item).html();
    });
    $('#productTable tr').has('td').each(function() {
        var arrayItem = {};
        $('td input, td select', $(this)).each(function(index) {
            arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(this).val();
        });
        array.push(arrayItem);
    });

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
 }

$(document).ready(function(){
    populateSelect(); 
  //  $('#productTable tbody tr:gt(0) :input').prop('disabled',true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="productTable" border="1">
     
    <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Product1</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Product2</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
         <td>
                  <select class="product1" > 
                  <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="description" value="">
    </td>
     <td>
                  <select class="product2" >        
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>  
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
         <td>
                  <select class="product1" >  
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
     <td>
   <input type="text" name="description" value="">
    </td>
     <td>
                  <select class="product2" >  
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
      <td>
     <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
          <td>
                  <select class="product1" >  
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
     <td>
   <input type="text" name="description" value="">
    </td>
     <td>
                  <select class="product2" >  
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
     <td>
     <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
    </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="orderNum" value=""></td>
          <td>
                  <select class="product1" > 
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
     <td>
   <input type="text" name="description" value="">
    </td>
     <td>
                  <select class="product2" >   
                   <option value=""></option>
                    </select>
    </td>
     <td>
     <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
    </td>
      </tr>
   
</table> <br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitData()">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your column loop, you don't want to assign the entire html of the cell. Rather, you need just the value of the select box that is contained in the cell.

In other words: change `$(item).html()` in your loop on the 'td's to `$(item).find('select').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part of code

```
$('#productTable tr').has('td').each(function() {
    var arrayItem = {};
    $('td input, td select', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
        arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).val();
    });
    array.push(arrayItem);
});
```

You are selecting the `<td>` html, but what you really want is the input and select values.